# Rust bubbles on paint

Tags: paint, rust, chassis-paint

On my 2011 Camry, the paint on my front left fender along the wheel well is bubbling up, with what I assume is rust underneath.  This fender was replaced a number of years ago after a fender bender.

What can I do to prevent it from getting worse, and/ or is there an easy way to fix it?  (Doesnt have to be perfect)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, when the rust bubbles appear under the paint, the rust started behind the paint, and possibly from the other side of the fender.  The replacement fender may have been an aftermarket unit specified by your insurance company to save money.

Preventing it from getting worse means sanding the paint and rust off, priming and repainting.  If you find rust-through, you will have to either patch it or replace the fender.  If you wind up going that route, try to source a used OEM fender from a salvage yard, the quality of the finish on the steel will likely be better.

Answer (score 1):

The replacement was not done properly , either cleaning or priming. Repair requires removing all paint to bare metal and proper painting. It would be worth considering the cost of a replacement fender/quarter panel; it may be lass expensive. I have done this a couple times , because my time is "free". I went with the time consuming sanding to remove paint.